# how to use div in el expression

Tags: jsp, el

I need to use a el expression like this :

`<td><c:out value="${list.div}"/></a></td>`

the 'div' is not  tag, it's one of the column name in my table.
but it doesn't work and causes error because editor consider my div as  tag.

Someone knows how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL `div` (/) is reserved word and should not be used as an identifier.

[JSP Reserved Words](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnail.html)

Comment: I knew, but we can't change our table desc so i was concerned if there is any method to use reserved word in el expression so

Comment: @HEROOriginal_ Why you can't change div name?

Comment: @HEROOriginal_ change programmatically database column name with annotation. @Column(name="div") private String anyWord. And access {list.anyWord}